# Give an example of a linear mapping T where $T^2=0$ holds but $kerT≠ImT$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

1. Give an example of a linear mapping T such that $kerT=ImT$.
2. Give an example of a linear mapping T ($T\neq O$) where $T^2=0$ holds but $kerT≠ImT$.

Attempt:

1. $T(x,y)=(y,0)$, $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}$ then $kerT=ImT=\{(1,0)\}$

Please check whether it is correct or not. Please help me to solve 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to 1 is fine.  For 2, it is notable that $T^2 = 0$ iff $im(T) \subseteq \ker(T)$.  One possible answer is
$$
T(x,y,z) = (y,0,0)
$$

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between 'helping to solve' and 'giving the answer'.

Comment: @Servaes Indeed, and this website is designed for people to *give answers*.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linear mapping $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ whose matrix with respect to the basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_ 3\}$ is $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0& 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$ Since

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0& 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0& 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0& 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ we have that $T^2=0.$ However the image and the kernel are different: the image has dimension one and the kernel dimension two.

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between 'helping to solve' and 'giving the answer'.

Comment: @Servaes Giving an answer to a question HELPS to solve similar questions. Don't you think?

Comment: In the least helpful possible way, yes. And the OP does not ask you to help solve similar questions, he/she asks you to help solve this question.